# How to have multiple rows in a node without setting `rankdir` nor using html tags

Tags: graphviz

I need to plot nodes which have two rows. The top row is node name, and the bottom row is a condition. I am currently using the html-style `table` tag to achieve this. However, somehow I dislike this way. So, I am wondering if there is a more concise way without using html-style tags to do this. Note that I don't want to change `rankdir=TB` to `rankdir=LR`.

An example of my current approach, including code and output, is attached below. Thank you in advance.

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=Mrecord] 
    aNode [ label=<
                <table border='0'>
                <tr><td bgcolor='gray'>nodeName</td></tr>
                <tr><td>condition</td></tr></table>
                > ];
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting {} around the text in your label will change the direction of the record separators.

```
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=TB];
    node [shape=Mrecord];
    item [label="{one | two}"];
}
```

[image: sample node]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One follow-up question: how can I style the top row, such as filling color, changing font color, etc.? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot do it with record-based nodes. Look at http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record for the record schema. You can change the font or the color for the complete record only.

Comment: self referencing but of note, you can have multiple "{" IE: {{one | two}}.  Useful if you want to use Record shap as above but with rankdir=LR.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386824/mrecord-shapes-orientations-and-rankdir?noredirect=1&lq=1